# Set value of primeng dropdown in model driven form

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to populate a form which has a few PrimeNg dropdowns.
For simplicity let me use example similar to what is on their web site.

```html
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <p-dropdown [options]="cities" formControlName="selectedCity"></p-dropdown>
</form>
```

```js
this.cities = [
  {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
  {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
  {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
  {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
  {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
];
```

So suppose user from table with his trips selects a row for edit.
It corresponds to some complex object, which contains a City property.
We need to programmatically select say Rome in that dropdown on the form.

I tried to do:

```
this.myFormGroup.get("selectedCity").setValue('Rome');
```

tried:

```
this.myFormGroup.get("selectedCity").patchValue('Rome');
```

tried adding to html:

```
optionLabel="name"
```

Nothing gets selected.

Any advice how to do it properly?

I assume I should not add

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
```

and do:

```
this.selectedCity='Rome';
```

Using Angular6 and PrimeNG 6.1.2.

Comment: So no value in that dropdown is displayed as selected. How to make that selected value displayed?    But this.myFormGroup.get("selectedCity").value shows Rome.     Note: that dropdown should be editable after that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all it should be clear that; whatever the `options` array contains they are the values set to the `FormControl`.

In this case form control values are city **objects** because `cities` array contains objects.

In order to set form control value programmatically, the value must be one of the elements from `options` array.

So, if you want to set `Istanbul` as selected you must set exact same object from `cities` array (particularly, `cities[3]`)

It can be done in this way;

```js
this.myFormGroup.get("selectedCity").setValue(this.cities.find(city => city.name === "Istanbul"));
```

As a side note `optionLabel="name"` only indicates which field from city objects to use as display value, that's all.

Here is a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-6yu6jz

Comment: Good answer, make sense and works for me.  I was just hoping PrimeNG might have some more intuitive way, say  function  setSelectedValue which does it, but could not find it.   Saw only selectedId attribute, but it didn't cut it for me.  I also noticed that in some case TS compiler doesn't like city.name, but works with city.label (I guess, referring to optionLabel).

Comment: I am happy to hear that i was helpful. I agree that something more intuitive can be done but currently this is the way it is. Can you also mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and upvote please?

Comment: As I mentioned, for my dropdowns, "in some case TS compiler doesn't like city.name, but works with city.label (I guess, referring to optionLabel). ".  I am getting TS error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'SelectItem' ". I do have as options array of objects like { id: '123', name: 'John Smith'} and optionLabel="name".  How can I fix that?

Comment: Please see **Getting Started** section in [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown)

Comment: I don't see answer in that Get started.  const valueObj = this.cities.find(city => city.name === 'New York');  doesn't compile, gives me that TS (2.9.2) error.  Any idea?

Comment: Actually, I've seen an interesting piece of code, where on form with multiple primeng dropdowns someone did  myformGroup.patchValue(formData), and that populated the whole form, that really puzzled me.  I noticed that there in JSON data they used mostly   not names (visible part), but Ids.  These dropdowns were independent. In my case some are cascading, so for example if "New York" selected, it sets list of options for next dropdows, say airports: [ { name: Kennedy, id: JFK}, {name: LaGuardia, id: LGA}, {name: Newark, id: EWR}] or for Philadelphia there is:  [{name: Philadelphia, id:PHL}]

Comment: As far as that TS error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'SelectItem' ".  it's my mistake, I had that data array as   cities: SelectedItem[];   it should be   cities: any[].  That fixed it, so now it can use any attribute in that data.    Still would like to see your comments on myformGroup.patchValue(formData);  how can that work regarding primeng  dropdowns, as I said, it work for someone.   Sorry, can't share the code, it is not public.    Also made cascading dropdowns work with setting individual dropdowns the way you suggested.

Comment: it is hard to say anything without seeing the code you mention about `patchValue`. However, i doubt that it gives you anything besides what you already have. Because `patchValue` works similarly to `setValue`. It is like a partial `setValue`. With `setValue` whole formgroup's and underlying formcontrols' values are set while `patchValue` can set a subset of child controls. That's it, it doesn't do any magic.

Comment: OK, one more question. If user manually selects dropdown value on the form, I am getting selectedCity={name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}, from the form, but I only need one of them, say  selectedCity='NY' code (and maybe selectedCityName='New York' on same form).   As I said, I have optionLabel="name"   Is there another property for that?